# Modal opens out of screen and then comes back inside screen after few seconds

Tags: modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I'm not a front end developer I have a modal when it opens or I made any operation it goes out of screen on left side and comes back to it's real state after few seconds. It happens only in mobile. I have also upload the images

[Image 1 bad modal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4dzPJ.png)
[Image 2 same modal change after few seconds](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5wKFu.png)